# She is gone! -dead or departed?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

I know that

> "is gone"

can be translated to both **"dead"** and really **"departed"** and in most cases I can understand that when I know the context. But sometimes even when I know the context I have hard times defining it. Is there any way to determine that?

i.e: I've started a movie right in the middle, a man was in a hurry to go to someones house from the bus station and when he arrived a girl (a common friend apparently) said: Sorry, she is gone.

I knew the context, but I didn't know the history so I guessed that she had to be dead, but after 10 minutes I understand that she's moved to another country :|

Comment: For what it's worth, *departed* is also a euphemism for *died*, as in set phrases like *the dearly departed* and *the faithful departed* (traditional translation of *fidelium animae defunctorum*).

Comment: This is sometimes ambiguous even to native speakers, and this ambiguity can be used intentionally by scriptwriters to confuse the characters and/or the audience. [There's even a trope.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoLongerWithUs)

Comment: If you didn't know the history, you didn't know the full context. But since movement is clear at the time of the statement, I would go with "departed" (went somewhere else). But "departed" is usually used in the case of scheduled travel, so using "left" would be more likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"She's gone", has to be in context to make sense. You just found that out!

> It could mean: She could not wait and left before you arrived.
>
> It could mean: She has left your relationship.
>
> It could mean: She's dead.
>
> It could mean: She left the building/country/city -- any place.

Comment: Unless there were a lot of people standing around looking sad, "she's dead" would not be my first interpretation.  It's more common to mean simply "she isn't here."